# Merging/Combining a list of Integers with Char [Haskell]

Tags: list, haskell, integer, char

I'd like a hint on how to apply this function:

`dti xs = (map intToDigit (take 6 (map digitToInt xs))++['/']++map intToDigit(drop 6 (map digitToInt xs)))`

on a list of Integers, e.g.; [1234567822,3245336792,...], so I'd get an output like ["123456/7822","324533/6792",...].

The point is to add a "/" after the 6th digit in each number of a list of integers, e.g.; [1234567822,3245336792,...]. Maybe there's a better way to do it than mine.

Comment: A solution with `splitAt` might be more elegant than a combination of `take` and `drop`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`intToDigit` expects a single digit, so it will raise an error on input like 1234567822.

To convert an `Int` (or `Integer`) into a list of characters, you can use `show`, and then split the resulting string after six digits

```
format n = first ++ '/':second
  where
    s = show n
    (first,second) = splitAt 6 s

dti = map format
```

Comment: I know code like `first ++ '/':second` is idiomatic, but I sometimes wish that the idiom was `first ++ "/" ++ second`.

Comment: I can understand that. But I just can't bring myself to wrapping a single character in a list only to immediately take it out again to stick it to the front of another list. That's so indirect.

Comment: @DanielFischer If you've chosen Haskell, you've already chosen not to care how indirect your computation is. Admit that you favor writing what you mean over thinking about how to compute what you mean. Anything else is doing the compiler's job for it; ghc produces the same core (up to alpha equivalence) for the two programs `main = getContents >>= putStr . ("/"++)` and `main = getContents >>= putStr . ('/':)`.

Comment: @DanielWagner I do care about the indirectness, can't help it;) Also, I haven't chosen Haskell, it chose me. Now it has to live with the consequences.